# tikz External: \tikzsetnextfilename and \tikzpicturedependsonfile

Tags: tikz-pgf, automation, tikz-external

Consider the following MWE. If `\tikzpicturedependsonfile` is commented out, the code runs as expected. `A.dep` is created stating the dependency of `A.pdf` on `A.dat`. Now, lets try to add the tikz source file `A.tikz` as a dependency.

However, if `\tikzpicturedependsonfile` is included in the code, then `\tikzsetnextfilename` does not have any effect and `main-figure0.pdf` is created instead of `A.pdf`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzscale,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]
%
\begin{filecontents}{A.tikz}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot [] table [header=false] {A.dat};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{A.dat}
  1 1 
  2 2 
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{document}
  \newcommand{\figFilename}{}
  \renewcommand{\figFilename}{A}
  \tikzsetnextfilename{\figFilename}
  \tikzpicturedependsonfile{\figFilename.tikz}
  \input{\figFilename.tikz}
\end{document}
```

The aim of this activity is to add the source file (`A.tikz`) for the `tikzpicture` to the dependency along with the data file (`A.dat`) which is added by default. Once this is achieved, any time a tikzpicture has been edited, it will get recompiled automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in the external library (present in PGF 2.10 and the copy shipped with pgfplots 1.7).

I have fixed it; it will be contained in the next PGF release. An updated copy is also shipped with pgfplots releases (provided you say `\usepgfplotslibrary{external}` instead of the tikz one).

The effect of the bug is that "get next filename" resets (a) the value which has been set by `\tikzsetnextfilename` and (b) the value of `export next`.

If you cannot wait, a work-around appears to be to move `\tikzsetnextfilename` *after* your line with `\tikzpicturedependsonfile`.

Comment: Do you perhaps know, when will the next official PGF/TikZ release be available?  It is about 2.5 years since the last one.

Answer (score 5):

Same cause as your other question ([tikzscale and \tikzsetnextfilename do not work together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87449/tikzscale-and-tikzsetnextfilename-do-not-work-together#comment189289_87449)), the filename gets globally reset after any call to `\tikzexternalgetnextfilename`. In this case, such a call is made by `\tikzpicturedependsonfile`. This one surely is a bug in TikZ!

Workaround (get `\tikzpicturedependsonfile` to reset the name if it calls `\tikzexternalgetnextfilename`):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\makeatletter
\def\tikzpicturedependsonfile@ACTIVE#1{%
    \begingroup
    \tikzexternalgetcurrentfilename\tikzpicturedependsonfile@name
    \ifx\tikzpicturedependsonfile@name\pgfutil@empty
        \tikzexternalgetnextfilename\tikzpicturedependsonfile@name
        \expandafter\tikzsetnextfilename\expandafter{\tikzpicturedependsonfile@name}
    \fi
    \expandafter\tikzexternalfiledependsonfile\expandafter{\tikzpicturedependsonfile@name}{#1}%
    \endgroup
}%
\makeatother

\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]
%
\begin{filecontents}{A.tikz}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot [] table [header=false] {A.dat};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{A.dat}
  1 1 
  2 2 
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{document}
  \newcommand{\figFilename}{}
  \renewcommand{\figFilename}{A}
  \tikzsetnextfilename{\figFilename}
  \tikzpicturedependsonfile{\figFilename.tikz}
  \input{\figFilename.tikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Lets wait for @christian-feuersanger 's comment.