# tikzscale and \tikzsetnextfilename

Tags: pgfplots, tikzscale

I'm using Windows 7 or 8.1 with MiKTeX 2.9. I still have the problems, described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87449/tikzscale-and-tikzsetnextfilename-do-not-work-together/88645#88645?newreg=dd23937ae89b4c10af8dc419f4f5d26b) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87530/tikz-external-tikzsetnextfilename-and-tikzpicturedependsonfile?rq=1).

I updated the packages with the package manager and I use

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikzscale,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
%
\begin{filecontents}{A.tikz}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\figFilename}{}
\renewcommand{\figFilename}{A}
\tikzpicturedependsonfile{\figFilename.tikz}
\tikzsetnextfilename{\figFilename}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\figFilename}
\end{document}
```

Instead of `A.pdf`, `main-figure0.pdf` is made and the figure is NOT scaled. From the mentioned threads I thought this bug is fixed. Without specifying the filename it's working fine.

Is there a special way to update the external library?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because with PGFPlots v1.14 one gets the desired output.