# TikZ External and tikzscale: Figure is regenerated every time

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, tikzscale

I am using `tikzscale` with `tikz external` library in the `list and make` mode. Before using `tikzscale`, if I issued `make -f main.makefile` command, only the figures that were not present would be generated. But since I have started using `tikzscale`, all the figures are regenerated even if they exist already. This takes a lot of time for compilation of a long document. Please go through the MWE and let me know if I have set up everything correctly.

The testing sequence on a `linux` machine is:

```
pdflatex main.tex
make -f main.makefile
ls -l main-figure0.pdf
make -f main.makefile
ls -l main-figure0.pdf
```

One can see that the figure is generated again from the timestamp.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]
%Comment out to external work properly without tikzscale
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\begin{filecontents}{fig.tikz}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig.tikz}
    %Uncomment to see externalize work properly without tikzscale
    %\input{fig.tikz}
    \caption{Test figure}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @MartinScharrer `external` works with `tikzpicture` `\input` from external files. Please see the modified MWE. Since `.dep` files are being create, I am assuming that `external` sees the environment. I will have to look into your package.

Comment: Sorry, forget me previous comments (I deleted them now including your response). `tikzscale` works differently then the mentioned `gincltex` because the latter scales the text size as well. `standalone` also doesn't have support for keeping the text size constant because it is not TikZ-specific. The `tikzscale` manual actually states in section 3.2 that it is compatible with the `external` library.

Comment: Did you see this in the `tikzscale` package? Section 4: *When the `external` library is used, the graphic files get regenerated more often than necessary. This is, because the axis ratio is not saved, thus assumed unknown and the graphic is thus regenerated. For performance reasons if a default axis ratio is used, the plot is not regenerated. If a nondefault
axis ratio has been used for generating the externalized graphic and the default axis ratio is used in the current run, this is not detected and the graphic has the wrong size at the moment. You can, of course, delete the [..]*

Comment: @MartinScharrer - Yes. That happens and written down in the `main-figure0.log` file. However, once the figure is generated, and there has been no change in the `figure.tikz` file and the `main.tex` file then the usual `external` behaviour of stating that all the figures are up-to-date doesn't happen if `tikzscale` is used. It keeps regenerating the figures with every `make` run.

Answer (score 1):

This might not really be a satisfactory answer, but it's too long for a comment and it is at least a workaround.

I do not recommend using `mode=list and make`, as the only real advantage I see (with a current version of the external library) is generating multiple figures in parallel (the security aspect should be negligible for documents being the author oneself). Unfortunately, at least with tikzscale, race conditions have been observed when using parallelisation. So avoiding `mode=list and make` does not seem to have any disadvantage in practice (this might change, of course, in the future), while being more comfortable, as tex does everything on its own.

That said, main-figure0.pdf is being regenerated with my installation independent of using tikzscale or not while using `mode=list and make` (TikZ installation from 26th of December 2012). This might be worth a bug report if you can reproduce that. When using the default mode, no file gets regenerated if it has not been changed. I tested this with version 0.2 of tikzscale, which seems to be a bit stuck on CTAN at the moment, but it can be downloaded from [github](https://github.com/MagicMuscleMan/tikzscale).

The above problem mentioned by Martin Scharrer is also fixed in version 0.2. With version 0.2, there is no case known, which would lead to an unnecessary regeneration (i.e. after the first tex run) with the extern library when using the default mode.